# React - show classname only if variable true

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className={ isTrue ? 'primary' : ''}>{ false ? 'selva' : 'ganapathi'}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

here `isTrue` varibale is `true` then the class name will be `primary`, but if the `isTrue` is variable is `false` it will show empty class in the DOM.

How to avoid this empty attribute?

[image: classenter image description here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform that by replacing in ternary operator `''` by `null` which will completely hide the `class` attribute when It's set to null

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isTrue: false
    }
    this.toggleState = this.toggleState.bind(this);
  }
  
  toggleState () {
    this.setState({isTrue: !this.state.isTrue});
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1 className={ this.state.isTrue ? 'primary' : null }>{ this.state.isTrue ? 'selva' : 'ganapathi'}</h1>
        
        <button onClick={this.toggleState}>Toggle</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: let j = {}
if(false) {
  j.className='primary'
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 {... j}>{ false ? 'selva' : 'ganapathi'}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

Answer (score 4):

You could pass `null` or `undefined` to your className to remove the prop.

Under the hood, `react` checks for those values and removes the prop for `null` and `undefined`.

```
<h1 className={ isTrue ? 'primary' : null}>{ false ? 'selva' : 'ganapathi'}</h1>
```

OR

```
<h1 className={ isTrue ? 'primary' : undefined}>{ false ? 'selva' : 'ganapathi'}</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be `null` instead of empty string

```
<h1 className={ isTrue ? 'primary' : null}>...
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers in the thread you can also do this concisely as this:

```js
<h1 className={ isTrue && 'primary' }>{ false ? 'selva' : 'ganapathi'}</h1>
```

This works pretty much the same way:

- If `isTrue` is `true` then the second part of the expression is checked and the entire expression evaluates to `primary`.
- If `isTrue` evaluates to `false`, react sets `className={false}` and it won't be set in your DOM.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [isTrue, setTrue] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className={ isTrue ? 'primary' : ''}>
        { isTrue ? 'selva' : 'ganapathi'}
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This still doesn't solve the OP's problem, please check carefully - you are doing the same thing he's doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

let j = {}
if(false) {
  j.className='primary'
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 {... j}>{ false ? 'selva' : 'ganapathi'}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

any one tell me how it works?